# Android - App crashes at re-launch after app being force closed by OS because of permission disabled

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity, android-lifecycle

Steps to produce the problem.

```
1) Launch Tasks.class activity
2) Hit home button puting the app in the background
3) Go to Settings->permissions and disable a permission which results in my app being force closed by the OS
4) Open app from launcher ---> app resumes Tasks.class activity instead of opening MainActivity --> CRASH
```

It crashed at `listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);` because listView was now null as were all class variables; Here is my activity. It uses the TasksFragment class as data retainer to handle orientation changes. When the TasksFragment is created it starts loading data with an AsyncTask and notifies the Activity when new data are fetched using the callbacks

```
public class Tasks extends FragmentActivity  implements TasksFragment.TaskCallbacks{

   TasksFragment f;
   FragmentManager fm;
   String TASKS_TAG="TASKS";
   searchList = new ArrayList<Task>();
   TaskAdapter mAdapter;
   ListView listView;

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_tasks);
      .
      .
      .
      fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
      f = (TasksFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(TASKS_TAG);
      if (f == null) {
          f = new TasksFragment();
          fm.beginTransaction().add(f, TASKS_TAG).commit();
      }
      else{
          preLoad();
          postLoad();
      } 

   }

   @Override        //TaskFragmentCallback
   public void onPreExecute() { 
       preLoad(); 
   }

   @Override        //TaskFragmentCallback
   public void onProgressUpdate(Task task) {
       searchList.add(task);
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   }

   @Override        //TaskFragmentCallback
   public void onCancelled() { }

   @Override       //TaskFragmentCallback
   public void onPostExecute() { 
       postLoad(); 
   }

   public void preLoad(){
       searchList = new ArrayList<Task>();
       mAdapter = new TaskAdapter(this,searchList,true); 
       listView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
   }

   public void postLoad(){
       searchList.clear();
       searchList.addAll(f.taskList);
       mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
   } 
}
```

I managed to make it not crash replacing the onPreExecute callback with

```
   @Override        //TaskFragmentCallback
   public void onPreExecute() { 
       if(listView!=null){ 
           preLoad();  
       }
   }
```

I used log statements to determine the sequence of events and I saw the following:

First app launch and lauch Tasks.class

```
ON ACTIVITY CREATE 
ON FRAGMENT CREATE 
on pre execute callback
preload called by callback   
ON ACTIVITY RESUME
```

On reopen after app termination while Tasks.class was open and app was put to background

```
ON FRAGMENT CREATE
on pre execute callback //this is where it would crash
ON ACTIVITY CREATE
preload called by activity because fragment!=null  
ON ACTIVITY RESUME
```

I can't understand why the fragment is created before the activity...who called this fragment to be created? Though the `if(listView!=null)` condition solved my problem I think it's a bandaid and not a real solution. Can someone shed some wisdom on this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

What I believe is happening (somebody correct me if I'm wrong) is that because you're artificially shutting down the application with `System.exit(0)` which is not a recommended practice (so far as I know) in Android, your Fragment isn't being cleanly detached. This results in the Fragment being resumed when you open the app back up.

The check you're doing `if (listView != null)` works because your Fragment is sort of a ghost. It still exists, but it's not attached to the activity and so it can't obtain a reference to the ListView you're trying to use. A similar, but more "valid" check might be `if (this.getActivity() != null)`.

Comment: I'm not using System.exit(0). I just mentioned that to simplify the question. What happens is that I went to my app's permissions in settings and disbaled a permission. Which results in android shutting down the app as if System.exit(0) would. This is something that a user could easily do and i would like to not result to a crash. I will edit the question to avoid further confusion

Answer (score 0):

From android System documentation

Causes the VM to stop running and the program to exit with the given exit status. **If runFinalizersOnExit(boolean) has been previously invoked with a true argument**, **then all objects will be properly garbage-collected and finalized first.**

Not sure it it will make a difference. Generally I never exit() an android program.

Comment: It also says runFinalizersOnExit(boolean) is deprecated and unsafe. So I guess I can't use that